# Passing property as object to method

Tags: c#, .net, validation, properties, anonymous-methods

I would like to build a helper method which will take property as object to anonymous method. This is just dummy code example to visualize problem not confront real solution which is way more complex and is not subject of this question.

Some reference code:

```
public class FooClass : SomeBaseClass {
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTimeProperty { get; set; }

    public Object ComplexObjectProperty { get; set; }

    public FooClass() {
        this.FooMethod(this.StringProperty);
        this.FooMethod(this.IntProperty);
        this.FooMethod(this.DateTimeProperty);
        this.FooMethod(this.ComplexObjectProperty);
    }

    public void FooMethod<T>(T obj) {
        Func<bool> validateMethod = () => {
            if(obj is string) return string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString());
            return obj != null;
        };
        this.ValidateMethodsAggregate.Add(validateMethod);
    }
}

public class SomeBaseClass {
    protected IList<Func<bool>> ValidateMethodsAggregate = new List<Func<bool>>();

    public void ValidateAll() {
        foreach (var validateMethod in this.ValidateMethodsAggregate) {
            var result = validateMethod();
            // has errors and so on handling...
        }
    }
}

// Some simple code to show use case.
        var foo = new FooClass();
        foo.StringProperty = "new value";
        foo.IntProperty = 123;
        foo.ValidateAll(); // this will use "" , 0 instead of new values.
```

Comment: So then why are you calling your validation method in the constructor? It's quite obvious that at this time the property will not have a value yet. Why don't you call the validation method at the appropriate time when `StringProperty` will have some value assigned to it?

Comment: You're getting the value of `StringProperty` in the constructor and  you never set it to anything. Of course it's going to be using the default value. If you want to defer reading the value, you can either change `FooMethiod()` to accept a `PropertyInfo` type and use reflection in the constructor to get that, or use a delegate like `FooMethod(() => StringProperty);`

Comment: You should take a look at [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).

Comment: Delegate or PropertyInfo is the answer.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I will check it out for sure, but currently I work In legacy framework which is more restricted about what can be used during validation process. Cheers.

Comment: @Patryk Let's see if you can avoid re-inventing the wheel and you can use an existing validation library... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function and a conditional operator with a private backing method

```
        public FooClass()
        {
            this.FooMethod(() => StringProperty); // <- pass an accessor
        }
        public Func<bool> validateMethod;
        private void FooMethod<T>(Func<T> obj)
        {
            //validate method
            validateMethod = () => string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj()?.ToString());
        }
```

The usage would be

```
        var y = new FooClass();
        var resTrue = y.validateMethod();
        y.StringProperty = "Hi";
        var resFalse = y.validateMethod();
```